# how do I intercept was pressed the F1 key on my main window?

Tags: delphi-xe2

How to do that when I'm in the main window of my system by pressing F1 will display the help muetre in pdf format. how do I intercept was pressed the F1 key on my main window?

I use Delphi XE2

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Application.OnHelpCommand` event, which you can either assign in code:

```
interface

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
     // IDE generated code
  private
    procedure AppOnHelp(Command: Word; Data: Integer; 
      var CallHelp: Boolean);
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.OnHelp := AppOnHelp;
end;
```

Or assign by using a `TApplicationEvents` component and creating a handler for the `OnHelp` event in the Object Inspector's Events tab.

You can set `CallHelp` to false to prevent the normal help processing, and launch your own help file via `ShellExecute`.

```
procedure TForm1.AppOnHelp(Command: Word; Data: Integer; 
      var CallHelp: Boolean);
begin
  CallHelp := False;
  // Launch your own help here
end;
```

Comment: I thought you accidentally missed that procedure doesn't have return types. visitor could use `function AppOnHelp(Command: Word; Data: NativeInt; var CallHelp: Boolean): Boolean;` instead of `procedure AppOnHelp(Command: Word; Data: Integer; var CallHelp: Boolean): Boolean;`

Comment: @cvsingh: Yes, you're correct. I've edited to fix it. Thank you for pointing that out. :-)